# C# Word Interop - "Find and replace" finds word but does not replace it

Tags: c#, replace, ms-word, find, interop

The below code is able to find the text I'm looking for, but when I go to replace it, the text is not replaced. I get no exceptions.

```
var word = new Application();
File.Delete(@"Your new test document.docx");
File.Copy(@"Your test document.docx", @"Your new test document.docx");
var document = word.Documents.Open(@"Your new test document.docx");
document.Activate();

while (document.Content.Find.Execute(FindText: "([Tag"))
{
    var stringToReplace = document.Content.Text.Substring(document.Content.Text.IndexOf("([Tag"), document.Content.Text.IndexOf("])") + 2 - document.Content.Text.IndexOf("([Tag"));
    var replacement = stringToReplace.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");

    if (document.Content.Find.Execute(FindText: stringToReplace))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stringToReplace);
        document.Content.Find.Execute(FindText: stringToReplace, ReplaceWith: replacement, Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Failed");
}

document.Close(true);
word.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(document);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(word);
Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadLine();
```

To test the code:

1. Create word document.
2. Paste the following into it:

   ([Tag FirstName] [Tag LastName])

   Address No.: 2

   Stackoverflow

   The pope who owns that rad car is named ([Tag FirstName], [Tag LastName])
3. Save and update file paths in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was working fine, I was mixing formfields and normal text and the "Find and replace" functionality ms-word offers could not work fully with that (again it was able to find it, but not replace it).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx) uses this example for replace

```
private void SearchReplace()
{
    Word.Find findObject = Application.Selection.Find;
    findObject.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Text = "find me";
    findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Replacement.Text = "Found";

    object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

You'll notice it declares `replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll` and then passes it into `findObject.Execute` whereas you pass `WdReplace.wdReplaceOne` in which will only replace the first item found.

Comment: The objective is to only replace one at a time, so that part is fine. I also have almost identical (same replacement code, but different scenario) code in another area and that actually works. I did try the code you posted though, and still no luck.